# on click the class has added but on clicking another the same class which was added is not removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

on clicking nav-icon class "show-menu" has added to the body,but on clicking class nav-close the class show-menu has not removed from the body

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.nav-icon').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            if(!$('body').hasClass("show-menu") ){
                $('body').addClass("show-menu");
            };
        });
        $('.nav-close').click(function(){
            if( $('body').hasClass("show-menu") ){
                $('body').removeClass("show-menu");
            };
        });
     });
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle ?

Comment: Be aware, you checking conditions are useless here and you just really need to add or remove class

Comment: You have to provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thank you for your reply john, its still not working

Comment: BUT can you provide MCVE? At least relevant HTML markup in question itself. Are element(s) or just class `.nav-close` added later in the DOM? Is the click handler called or not? So what is not 'working'? Etc... And again, your checking condition are useless here, your code E.g could be just `e.stopPropagation(); $('body').addClass("show-menu");` because if it has already the class, adding it again has no effect. The same can be said from other click handler regarding removing class

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your functions outside `$(document).ready(function(){});` only put functions inside `$(document).ready` when you want you execute the functions when the page or DOM elements are loaded i don't think you need to place your code inside it.